# Get Gulp watch to perform function only on changed file

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

I am new to Gulp and have the following Gulpfile

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('compress', function () {
    return gulp.src('js/*.js') // read all of the files that are in js with a .js extension
      .pipe(uglify()) // run uglify (for minification)
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js')); // write to the dist/js file
});

// default gulp task
gulp.task('default', function () {

    // watch for JS changes
    gulp.watch('js/*.js', function () {
        gulp.run('compress');
    });

});
```

I would like to configure this to rename, minify and save only my changed file to the dist folder. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I watch mutliple files with gulp-browserify but process only one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818188/how-do-i-watch-mutliple-files-with-gulp-browserify-but-process-only-one)

Answer (score 13):

**This is how:**

```
// Watch for file updates
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    livereload.listen();

    // Javascript change + prints log in console
    gulp.watch('js/*.js').on('change', function(file) {
        livereload.changed(file.path);
        gutil.log(gutil.colors.yellow('JS changed' + ' (' + file.path + ')'));
    });

    // SASS/CSS change + prints log in console
    // On SASS change, call and run task 'sass'
    gulp.watch('sass/*.scss', ['sass']).on('change', function(file) {
        livereload.changed(file.path);
        gutil.log(gutil.colors.yellow('CSS changed' + ' (' + file.path + ')'));
    });

});
```

Also great to use [gulp-livereload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-livereload) with it, you need to install the [Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei?hl=en) for it to work btw.

Comment: Is there a way to respect the glob? `file.path` returns the absolute path so `**` are not respected when it comes to `gulp.dest()`.

Comment: @Markus.  look at `gulp-changed`

Answer (score 2):

See [incremental builds on the Gulp docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp#incremental-builds).

> You can filter out unchanged files between runs of a task using the gulp.src function's since option and gulp.lastRun

Comment: thanks @James your answer led me to my fuller answer

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you are using gulp 4.0.2 or 3.9.1 (solution for both below)

**If using gulp 4.0.2** you want to use the `gulp.src` function's `since` option and `gulp.lastRun`

```
const images = () => {
  return gulp.src(paths.images.src, {since: gulp.lastRun(images)})
    .pipe(imagemin({optimizationLevel: 5}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.images.dest));
}
```

Full docs [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/v4.0.2#incremental-builds)

***If using gulp 3.9.1*** I would recommend using [gulp-cached](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cached) and [gulp-remember](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-remember) - example:

```
const gulp = require('gulp')
const cache = require('gulp-cached')
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css')
const remember = require('gulp-remember')
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('node-sass'))
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps')
// const tap = require('gulp-tap')
// const util = require('gulp-util')

gulp.task('scss', () => {
  return gulp.src(paths.scss.basic)
    // .pipe(tap(file => util.log('scss', file.path)))
    .pipe(cache('scss1')) // 81 FILES
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(remember('scss1')) // 81 FILES
    .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(cache('scss2')) // 10 FILES
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(remember('scss2')) // 10 FILES
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(cache('scss3')) // 5 FILES
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./../../css'))
})
```

This is quite a complex example - generally `gulp-cached` should only be used where there is a 1:1 mapping in the stream. However, if you have a file count that changes as the stream progresses (e.g. when using `gulp-concat`) use `gulp-remember` in conjunction with `gulp-cached`. In the example above, `gulp-cached` is used  when there is a new file count and `gulp-remember` is used before the file count changes. If you don't know the file count at various places in the stream then use `util.log` to see what's going on. Notice that the cache name changes, the cache and remember statements are paired by cache name!

NB file count here refers to the number of files passing through the stream before caching

Other gulp plugins that try to do the same thing but that don't improve things if file count changes are [gulp-changed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-changed) and [gulp-newer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-newer). For a full gulp 3.9.1 list see [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/v3.9.1#incremental-builds)

NB `gulp-changed` supports gulp 3.9.1 (`gulp-changed@3.2.0`) and gulp 4.0.2 (`gulp-changed@latest`)